# Create EditText above soft keyboard on button click

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-manifest, android-softkeyboard, floating-action-button

I want to create an EditText above soft keyboard on button click.

Only when i click the floating button i want the soft keyboard up and put an EditText above it.

The floating button should disappear (Or for example ad banner to be hidden).

The solution i saw in many answers is add the following to manifest :

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

however this doesn't helping me because it makes the add add banner to show as well .
(I can programmatically hide the bannerand hide the floating button and after closing the keyboard show them again but i'm looking for a better solution )

[image]

Comment: Why do you consider adding a "banner" to be a bad solution?

Comment: The ad banner is just an example .